# What are the logos for the Jedi ranks?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I've researched a lot and didn't found many logos for Jedi ranks.
This is list of ranks I found, but not many logos.

[image: This is a complicated table with 5 categories, "Mercenary," "Loyalist," "Sith," "Gray/Dark Jedi," and "Jedi" and 4 "Tiers," each divided into 3 or 4 levels listing, for example, 12 ranks specific to "Loyalist" in addition to 3 ranks shared across categories. The provenance of this table is not given, nor the source of such Jedi ranks as "Vanguard."]

Comment: Where did you get this chart? I'm not sure I completely agree with it.

Comment: https://discourse.darkjedibrotherhood.com/t/maa-magistrates-novitiates-dark-jedi-brotherhood/958
if you have better idea of what can ranks be, please share it.

Comment: To be honest, the only jedi ranks I've heard of are youngling, padawan, knight, master.  The Sith in the movies/shows there's only master and apprentice.

Comment: Just get on your computer and type in "images of new Jedi order symbol" to see the new symbol. It's a rebel symbol but it has a sunlike background: http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/2/20/New_Jedi_Order.svg This is Grand Jedi Master Menice snow Decker. As I said in my earlier answer, there are no logos for Jedi ranks. Only the cadets get a logo, but I'm not sure what it's called yet. Give me a few days to find out. A.S.A.P.:-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before we begin, two disclaimers:

- The chart presented in the question is a fan construction, with only minimal support from *Star Wars* lore. Although there were a wide variety of [Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Jedi_ranks) and [Sith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Sith_ranks) ranks in Legends material, the rigid hierarchy implied in the question simply didn't exist. Likewise, there's no unified rank structure for "Grey Jedi" in Legends, because the Grey Jedi were [not a formal organization](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/38568/31051), but rather a catch-all term for a large number of disparate groups.
- Everything below is Legends only; to the best of my knowledge, no rank-specific logos or insignia have migrated to canon, with the exception of the Youngling logo described in the answers below.

Insignia - of a sort - for the core Jedi ranks are given in *The Jedi Path: A Manual for Students of the Force*:

[image]

It's worth pointing out that each insignia is a character in [Aurebesh](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aurebesh), the *Star Wars* in-universe alphabet; they correspond, in order, to the Aurebesh characters for "I", "P", "K", and "M". It seems a little odd to call these "insignia", and it's not clear how (or if) they're used in-universe, but there you go.

Later on, insignia are also given for the four branches of the Jedi Service corps:

[image]

As well, at least six of the Youngling "clans" all have logos<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> Thame and Ahsoka's margin notes indicate that other clans exist, and the text itself confirms this (emphasis mine):

> These **and the Temple's other clans** are the roots of the tree that sustains us as an Order.
>
> <sup>*The Jedi Path: A Manual for Students of the Force* Part 2: "Jedi Initiate" Chapter 1: "Joining a Clan"</sup>

The logos for these other clans, if they exist, are not recorded in this book.

Comment: Are the Aurebesh characters appear to be hand written in? They look darker and appear to have pressure marks (i.e. written with a pen or sorts). Great Find BTW! Also, looks like this manual has made the round! Yoda, Anakin, and (presumably) a Sith have all written in it!

Comment: @Skooba Hard to say; it's possible, but the diagram of the Jedi Service Corps has similar lines. It may just be a stylistic decision. And yes, this book has margin notes from Luke, Qui-Gon, Obi-Wan, Anakin, Ahsoka Tano, Yoda, Dooku, Sidious, and Dooku's old master Thame

Answer (score 2):

Having skimmed through the [Wookieepedia's article on Jedi Order](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Order), it appears that only [younglings](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_youngling) have their own symbol. It was apparently introduced in the episode 6 of season 5 of *Clone Wars*, titled "The Gathering". The corresponding [entry on the official *Star Wars* website](https://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/the-gathering-trivia-gallery) provides an image:

[image]

[Youngling's Wookieepedia page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_youngling) provides a [cleaner image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30MzZ.jpg).

Comment: Note that this answer was born while editing [this answer (now deleted)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/146253/70236); [relevant meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11259/70236).

Answer (score 1):

To address some of the comments, this does not appear to be an official Star Wars chart.

The [Jedi Order](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Order) has the following listed ranks:

- Youngling
- Padawan
- Knight
- Master
- Grand Master

The Jedi Order has a symbol, but from what I could find the individual ranks do not.

[image: A circular crest with what appear to be wings filling space on either side of an six-pointed star set below centre on a spike that rises from the bottom to the top]