# Who is the Grand Inquisitor?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

I just watched the *Star Wars Rebels* episode "Shroud of Darkness". In it, Kanan, Ezra, and Ashoka go to the Jedi temple on Lothal and meditate so that they can contact Yoda.

> During Kanan's vision, he fights three temple guards. When he finally realizes that he has to submit and accept his fate, the lead guard dubs him a Knight of the Jedi Order and then reveals that he is the Grand Inquisitor and that he was once a Jedi himself.

**Is there any canonical proof of who the Grand Inquisitor was before he was the Grand Inquisitor and, if so, did he serve in the Clone Wars?**

Comment: I think the answer below is the best we can do, but let me know if you are looking for more.

Comment: Sorry I was going to accept it but I completely forgot

Comment: No worries --- and a belated welcome to the site!  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In "Shroud of Darkness" we learn not only that the Grand Inquisitor was a Jedi, as you have pointed out, but furthermore that he was a **Temple Guard at the Jedi Temple on Coruscant**.

That is, however, the extent of what is confirmed in canon.  As indicated in the entry concerning the Grand Inquisitor in the official StarWars.com databank:

> ***Not much is known about the Empire’s Grand Inquisitor.*** A Pau’an male, he was tasked by Darth Vader to hunt down any surviving Jedi Knights. The Inquistor was an intimidating figure, dressed in all black and wielding a red, double-bladed lightsaber. After several encounters with Kanan Jarrus and his Padawan Ezra Bridger, the Inquisitor died in a lightsaber duel with Kanan — but warned the rogue Jedi that his victory had unleashed something terrible.

([Source](http://www.starwars.com/databank/the-grand-inquisitor))

In particular, we know nothing of his record during the Clone Wars.

One further thing to add is that the credits for "Shroud of Darkness" refer to the Inquisitor as ***Sentinel***, although it is unclear if this is a proper name or simply a description.

Comment: A [recent interview with Dave FIloni](http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-producer-of-star-wars-rebels-answers-your-burning-q-1768048083) revealed a bit more about the Grand Inquisitor

Comment: @JasonBaker : Interesting!  Is it okay if I add that in? :-)

Comment: By all means; that's why I left it as a comment